# No such file or directory after installing pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I installed pipenv in my Ubuntu 20.04 with the following command:

```sh
pip3 install --user pipenv
```

but now when I try to run `pipenv` or `pipenv shell` the terminal doesn't recognize it:

```
bash: /usr/bin/pipenv: No such file or directory
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to run `pipenv` with the python associated with the pip3.

so `python3 -m pipenv shell` considers that `pip3` is associaed with `python3`.

If it is not working then you can install `pipenv` again with the python as

`python3 -m pip install pipenv`

and `python3 -m pipenv shell`